# Using variables inside subprocess.popen in python

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

Hello all,
                I am new to python.
I am trying to execute a shell command inside python

The syntax of the shell command is like this --> **programme.sh -ip  -hostname  --old_ip  --old_host**

This is my python code

```
  import socket
 import subprocess
 from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT


   class Hosts:
   returncode = 0
   hostname = socket.gethostname()
ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
# print(hostname)
def __init__(self):
    self.h = socket.gethostname()
    self.n = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

def changeaddr(self):
     a=Hosts.hostname
     cmd='programme.sh -host a -ip Hosts.ip  -host_old <old host name> -host_ip x.x.x.x'
     cmd_new='programme.sh --continue'
     p=Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True )
     output=str(p.stdout.read())
     #print(output)
     status=output.find("error")
     if (status != -1):
       print("error encountered")
     else:
       p_new=Popen(cmd_new, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True )
       final_output=str(p_new.stdout.read())
       print(final_output)
      if __name__ == "__main__":
         h=Hosts()
         h.changeaddr()
```

The problem here is inside the cmd , the variables a and Hosts.ip are not interpolating to their values and being treated as a and Hosts.ip only , causing the shell command to fail

Can some ple guide me how to workaround this problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure the cmd string has right values:

```
cmd='programme.sh -host ' + a + ' -ip ' + Hosts.ip + ' -host_old <old host name> -host_ip x.x.x.x'
```

Comment: so please mark the answer as 'accepted' :)) : https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer